# Как получить текст из инпута?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events, event-loop

Подскажите, как получить текст из инпута? Есть такой код:

```
function createAddBlock() {
  const $addBlock = document.createElement('div');
  const $selectContacts = document.createElement('select');
  const $phoneOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $additionalPhoneOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $emailOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $vkOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $twitterOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $selectInput = document.createElement('input');

  $addBlock.classList.add('add-contact__contacts');
  $selectContacts.classList.add('add-contact__select');
  $selectInput.classList.add('add-contact__input');

  $phoneOption.textContent = 'Телефон';
  $phoneOption.value = 'phone';
  $additionalPhoneOption.textContent = 'Доп. тел.';
  $additionalPhoneOption.value = 'additional-phone';
  $emailOption.textContent = 'Email';
  $emailOption.value = 'email';
  $vkOption.textContent = 'Vk';
  $vkOption.value = 'vk';
  $twitterOption.textContent = 'Twitter';
  $twitterOption.value = 'twitter';
  $selectInput.placeholder = 'Введите данные контакта';

  $selectContacts.append($phoneOption, $additionalPhoneOption, $emailOption, $vkOption, $twitterOption);
  $addBlock.append($selectContacts, $selectInput);

  return $addBlock
}
```

Данная функция создает блок, которая впоследствии используется здесь:

```
$btnAddContact.addEventListener('click', () => {
  $btnAddContact.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', $addBlock)
})
```

Мне нужно получить value у $selectInput, чтобы потом value отображался при рендере данных, здесь:

```
$form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const client = {
    id: getID(dataClients),
    name: $inputName.value.trim(),
    surname: $inputSurname.value.trim(),
    lastname: $inputLastname.value.trim(),
    createDate: new Date(),
    changesDate: new Date(),
    contacts: getSelectInputValue(),
  }

  $inputName.value = '';
  $inputSurname.value = '';
  $inputLastname.value = '';

  dataClients.push(client);

  renderClients();
})
```

Но к сожалению, value не отображается. Добавил функцию в form

```
function getSelectInputValue() {
    let res = null;
    let nodes = createBlock().childNodes;
    res = nodes[1];

    return res.value
  }
```

Теперь форма выглядит так:

```
$form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  function getSelectInputValue() {
    let res = null;
    let nodes = createBlock().childNodes;
    res = nodes[1];

    return res.value
  }
  console.log(getSelectInputValue());

  const client = {
    id: getID(dataClients),
    name: $inputName.value.trim(),
    surname: $inputSurname.value.trim(),
    lastname: $inputLastname.value.trim(),
    createDate: new Date(),
    changesDate: new Date(),
    // contacts: getSelectInputValue(),
  }

  $inputName.value = '';
  $inputSurname.value = '';
  $inputLastname.value = '';

  dataClients.push(client);

  renderClients();
})
```

Выдает пустое value на выходе. Что нужно исправить?