# Как неоднократно добавить блок и добавлять кнопку, если инпут не пустой?

Tags: javascript, события

Как добавить блок неоднократно по нажатию кнопки? Код создания блока:

```
const $addBlock = document.createElement('div');
const $selectContacts = document.createElement('select');
const $phoneOption = document.createElement('option');
const $additionalPhoneOption = document.createElement('option');
const $emailOption = document.createElement('option');
const $vkOption = document.createElement('option');
const $twitterOption = document.createElement('option');
const $selectInput = document.createElement('input');
const $clearBtn = document.createElement('button');

$addBlock.classList.add('add-contact__contacts');
$selectContacts.classList.add('add-contact__select');
$selectInput.classList.add('add-contact__input');
$clearBtn.classList.add('add-contact__clear-input', 'btn-reset');

$selectContacts.append($phoneOption, $additionalPhoneOption, $emailOption, $vkOption, $twitterOption);
$addBlock.append($selectContacts, $selectInput, $clearBtn);
```

(Дополнение) Сначала, была такая функция для создания блока, но затем я ее убрал, т.к. не мог получить значение $selectInput:

```
function createAddBlock() {
  const $addBlock = document.createElement('div');
  const $selectContacts = document.createElement('select');
  const $phoneOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $additionalPhoneOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $emailOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $vkOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $twitterOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $selectInput = document.createElement('input');

  $addBlock.classList.add('add-contact__contacts');
  $selectContacts.classList.add('add-contact__select');
  $selectInput.classList.add('add-contact__input');

  $phoneOption.textContent = 'Телефон';
  $phoneOption.value = 'phone';
  $additionalPhoneOption.textContent = 'Доп. тел.';
  $additionalPhoneOption.value = 'additional-phone';
  $emailOption.textContent = 'Email';
  $emailOption.value = 'email';
  $vkOption.textContent = 'Vk';
  $vkOption.value = 'vk';
  $twitterOption.textContent = 'Twitter';
  $twitterOption.value = 'twitter';
  $selectInput.placeholder = 'Введите данные контакта';

  $selectContacts.append($phoneOption, $additionalPhoneOption, $emailOption, $vkOption, $twitterOption);
  $addBlock.append($selectContacts, $selectInput);

  return {
    $selectInput,
    $addBlock,
  };
}
```

Событие по клику, которое вставляет блок выше:

```
$btnAddContact.addEventListener('click', () => {
  $btnAddContact.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', $addBlock);

  $clearBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    $selectInput.value = '';
  })
})
```

Событие работает один раз, после уже не добавляет блоки. Что нужно исправить или дописать?

Также есть проблема с проверкой инпута на значение. Необходимо, чтобы проверка проходила по `$selectInput`. Если есть значение, то кнопка `$clearBtn` должна появиться, если значение пустое, то `$clearBtn` необходимо скрыть.

Пробовал так:

```
if ($selectInput.value.length !== 0) {
  $clearBtn.style.display = 'inline'
} else {
  $clearBtn.style.display = 'none'
}
```

Были еще такие варианты:

```
if ($selectInput.value) {
  $clearBtn.style.display = 'block';
}
if (!$selectInput.value) {
  $clearBtn.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Писал данный код и в событие по клику `$btnAddContact.addEventListener`, и после присоединения в `$addBlock`. Но код только скрывает кнопку, т.е. первое условие никогда не срабатывает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Начнем с того, что при каждом клике на  `$btnAddContact` у вас создается новый обработчик  `$clearBtn.addEventListener('click'`. Так же в коде не приведено, какая функция создает эти ваш новые блоки и где и как вы выстроили проверки.

Comment: Создание блока убрал из функции, т.к. тогда не получалось получить значение $selectInput. А проверку писал в событии $btnAddContact.addEventListener и после апенда $addBlock

Comment: У уже создавал вопрос по поводу получения текста из инпута, вот здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1527947/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, забыл добавить событие для инпута